# web service calling from console app, web service unable to connect the azure database

Tags: windows, web-services, azure, azure-sql-database

we want to connect the Azure database by using console application. my application sheduled in system it has dynamic IP. so i have problem to connect Sql Azure.

then developed a webservice and hosted in windows azure and consumed the web service from console still we have same issue.

please suggest

Comment: Have you configured the firewall rules for SQL Azure properly? Especially you would need to allow access to "Microsoft Services".

Comment: What is the error you're having when connect to the AZ DB ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IP range, you can allow the entire range on the database firewall. It's not very elegant but will work.